# special character displayed not well in display templates

Tags: display-template, special-characters

I have built some display templates which are showing some content. I see sometimes that the special characters are not showed very well.

See picture below for example. The text needs to be: `Alle categorieën`.

[image]

Why do I see this character: �

Comment: Please post your displaytemplate code / markup, seems like an encoding issue

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I found the solution. The encoding was wrong.